# Como cambiar el color a las líneas del grafico en Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

en un gráfico de líneas, qusiera cambiar el color de las curvas  que representan la variación de los datos. Por ejemplo, en la página de  Highcharts, hay una ejemplo con código, html, css y javascript que se denomina Monthly Average Temperature. La páina es "https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/accessibility-module".
Yo personalicé este gráfico modificando el código, para representar solo dos curvas . Pero a la hora de querer cambiar el color de las curvas representativas, no encuentro la forma, busqué en este foro y aparece solamente el cambio de color en gráficos de barra.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline'
  },
  accessibility: {
    point: {
      descriptionFormatter: function (p) {
        return p.series.name + ', ' + p.category + ', ' + p.y + 'kg.';
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Curvas de Tracción Fuerza en la llanta / Velocidad'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Comparación de Curvas y análisis'
  },
  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Velocidad (Km/h)'
    },
    categories: [
      'January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December'
    ],
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Fuerza (Kg)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">{point.key} valor</span><br/>',
    valueSuffix: 'kg.'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'New York',
    data: [30.7, 31.5, 39, 49.8, 60.8, 70.2, 75.6, 73.8, 66.9, 55.9, 44.8, 34.5]
    
  }, 
  

  {
    name: 'General Motors',
    data: [65.5, 67.1, 72.1, 79.2, 86.7, 90.1, 95.0, 95.0, 90.5, 84.2, 76.3, 68.7]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Por favor incluye tu código. Ve a [edit]

Answer (score 0):

en el apartado series agregas el color, ejemplo:

```js
series: [{
    color: '#17A54D',
    name: 'New York',
    data: [30.7, 31.5, 39, 49.8, 60.8, 70.2, 75.6, 73.8, 66.9, 55.9, 44.8, 34.5]

  },{
    color: '#F3C990',
    name: 'General Motors',
    data: [65.5, 67.1, 72.1, 79.2, 86.7, 90.1, 95.0, 95.0, 90.5, 84.2, 76.3, 68.7]
  }]
```

Comment: muchas gracias Antonio!!! Me sirvió y agradezco compartas tus conocimientos!!!!

Comment: Excelente amigo, solo una cosa, cuando hagas una pregunta y la respuesta que te den te sorba, puntuala con la flechita hacia arriba, eso ayuda a indicar que la pregunta ha tenido solución, suerte.

Comment: Disculpas ahora me di cuenta lo de la puntuación!!! te agradezco el comentario, hoy aprendí algo de tí!!! gracias!!! lo tendré en cuenta